# Embedded wireless DISABLED, how to enable. Fn keys? Laptop: MiniSamsung N250P/N145P Card: Intel Centrino Wireless-N 100 OS:Fedora34

Tags: fedora, wifi, network-interface, intel, samsung

I made sure to check Intel's support page and download the firmware just in case the kernel didn't contain it (it did) and then I went on to apply all the usual advice for troubleshooting wifi cards that won't load. Everything looks fine, except that the card doesn't load. Ethernet works fine, wifi works fine if I use a TPlink USB key.

```
  *-network DISABLED
 description: Wireless interface
   product: Centrino Wireless-N 100
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
   logical name: wlp5s0
   version: 00
   serial: [REMOVED]
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.13.12-200.fc34.x86_64 firmware=39.31.5.1 build 32895 100-5.uco latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:31 memory:f0100000-f0101fff
```

The other two network devices are:

```
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: enp9s0
       version: 00
       serial: [REMOVED]
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sky2 driverversion=1.30 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:29 memory:f0200000-f0203fff ioport:2000(size=256)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:1
       logical name: wlp0s29f7u1
       serial: [REMOVED]
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8188eu driverversion=5.13.12-200.fc34.x86_64 ip=[REMOVED] multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

Likewise, here's the module list. I'm at my wits' end here. Pointers would be appreciated.

```
Module                  Size  Used by
snd_seq_dummy          16384  0
snd_hrtimer            16384  1
r8188eu               479232  0
lib80211               16384  1 r8188eu
nft_fib_inet           16384  1
nft_fib_ipv4           16384  1 nft_fib_inet
nft_fib_ipv6           16384  1 nft_fib_inet
nft_fib                16384  3 nft_fib_ipv6,nft_fib_ipv4,nft_fib_inet
nft_reject_inet        16384  4
nf_reject_ipv4         16384  1 nft_reject_inet
nf_reject_ipv6         20480  1 nft_reject_inet
nft_reject             16384  1 nft_reject_inet
nft_ct                 20480  10
nft_chain_nat          16384  4
ip6table_nat           16384  0
ip6table_mangle        16384  0
ip6table_raw           16384  0
ip6table_security      16384  0
iptable_nat            16384  0
nf_nat                 49152  3 ip6table_nat,nft_chain_nat,iptable_nat
nf_conntrack          163840  2 nf_nat,nft_ct
nf_defrag_ipv6         24576  1 nf_conntrack
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack
iptable_mangle         16384  0
iptable_raw            16384  0
iptable_security       16384  0
ip_set                 61440  0
nf_tables             253952  240 nft_ct,nft_reject_inet,nft_fib_ipv6,nft_fib_ipv4,nft_chain_nat,nft_reject,nft_fib,nft_fib_inet
nfnetlink              20480  3 nf_tables,ip_set
ip6table_filter        16384  0
ip6_tables             36864  5 ip6table_filter,ip6table_raw,ip6table_nat,ip6table_mangle,ip6table_security
iptable_filter         16384  0
sunrpc                647168  1
iTCO_wdt               16384  0
at24                   24576  0
intel_pmc_bxt          16384  1 iTCO_wdt
gpio_ich               16384  0
iTCO_vendor_support    16384  1 iTCO_wdt
samsung_laptop         24576  0
iwldvm                270336  0
mac80211             1142784  1 iwldvm
uvcvideo              118784  0
coretemp               20480  0
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
iwlwifi               352256  1 iwldvm
videobuf2_v4l2         36864  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       69632  4 videobuf2_vmalloc,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_memops
snd_hda_codec_realtek   155648  1
videodev              278528  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
snd_hda_codec_generic    98304  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          16384  1 snd_hda_codec_generic
cfg80211             1007616  4 iwldvm,iwlwifi,mac80211,r8188eu
joydev                 28672  0
snd_hda_intel          57344  2
pcspkr                 16384  0
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     20480  1 snd_intel_dspcfg
mc                     65536  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
snd_hda_codec         172032  3 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
i2c_i801               32768  0
i2c_smbus              20480  1 i2c_i801
lpc_ich                28672  0
snd_hda_core          110592  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
rfkill                 32768  4 samsung_laptop,cfg80211
snd_seq                90112  7 snd_seq_dummy
snd_seq_device         16384  1 snd_seq
snd_pcm               135168  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
snd_timer              49152  3 snd_seq,snd_hrtimer,snd_pcm
snd                   110592  15 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd
acpi_cpufreq           32768  1
fuse                  167936  3
zram                   24576  2
ip_tables              28672  5 iptable_filter,iptable_security,iptable_raw,iptable_nat,iptable_mangle
i915                 2867200  3
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        290816  1 i915
cec                    61440  2 drm_kms_helper,i915
drm                   630784  4 drm_kms_helper,i915
serio_raw              20480  0
sky2                   73728  0
video                  57344  2 i915,samsung_laptop
```

From the journalctl, it's always

```
Aug 26 12:45:55 MiniSamsung wpa_supplicant[777]: wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-100

    Aug 26 12:46:55 MiniSamsung NetworkManager[731]: <info>  [1629996415.3046] device (wlp5s0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to F2:46:25:48:D0:17 (scanning)
Aug 26 12:46:55 MiniSamsung kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Radio type=0x0-0x0-0x3
Aug 26 12:46:56 MiniSamsung kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
Aug 26 12:46:58 MiniSamsung kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
Aug 26 12:46:58 MiniSamsung kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
Aug 26 12:46:58 MiniSamsung NetworkManager[731]: <warn>  [1629996418.1368] platform-linux: do-change-link[3]: failure changing link: failure 5 (Input/output error)

Aug 26 12:51:48 MiniSamsung wpa_supplicant[777]: wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-100
Aug 26 12:51:55 MiniSamsung NetworkManager[731]: <info>  [1629996715.2492] device (wlp5s0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to BE:F7:0E:CD:51:C5 (scanning)
Aug 26 12:51:55 MiniSamsung kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Radio type=0x0-0x0-0x3
Aug 26 12:51:55 MiniSamsung kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
Aug 26 12:51:58 MiniSamsung NetworkManager[731]: <warn>  [1629996718.1100] platform-linux: do-change-link[3]: failure changing link: failure 5 (Input/output error)
Aug 26 12:51:58 MiniSamsung kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
Aug 26 12:51:58 MiniSamsung kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
Aug 26 12:51:58 MiniSamsung wpa_supplicant[777]: wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-100
```

I tried reconfiguring it using the nm-cli

```
Aug 26 13:00:01 MiniSamsung sudo[3991]:   usenet : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/usenet ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/networkctl reconfigure wlp5s0
Aug 26 13:00:01 MiniSamsung audit[3991]: CRED_REFR pid=3991 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_env,pam_fprintd acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'
Aug 26 13:00:01 MiniSamsung sudo[3991]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=1000)
Aug 26 13:00:01 MiniSamsung audit[3991]: USER_START pid=3991 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:session_open grantors=pam_keyinit,pam_limits,pam_keyinit,pam_limits,pam_systemd,pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'
Aug 26 13:00:01 MiniSamsung audit[3991]: USER_END pid=3991 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:session_close grantors=pam_keyinit,pam_limits,pam_keyinit,pam_limits,pam_systemd,pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'
Aug 26 13:00:01 MiniSamsung audit[3991]: CRED_DISP pid=3991 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_env,pam_fprintd acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'
Aug 26 13:00:01 MiniSamsung sudo[3991]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Aug 26 13:00:10 MiniSamsung wpa_supplicant[777]: wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-100
```

My final attempt gave this:

```
Aug 26 14:43:41 MiniSamsung wpa_supplicant[777]: wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-100
Aug 26 14:45:42 MiniSamsung NetworkManager[731]: <info>  [1630003542.2232] device (wlp5s0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to 7E:2A:E0:B5:43:E5 (scanning)
Aug 26 14:45:42 MiniSamsung kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Radio type=0x0-0x0-0x3
Aug 26 14:45:42 MiniSamsung kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
Aug 26 14:45:44 MiniSamsung systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Deactivated successfully.
░░ Subject: Unit succeeded
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░ 
░░ The unit systemd-hostnamed.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Aug 26 14:45:45 MiniSamsung audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=systemd-hostnamed comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Aug 26 14:45:45 MiniSamsung kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
Aug 26 14:45:45 MiniSamsung kernel: iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
Aug 26 14:45:45 MiniSamsung wpa_supplicant[777]: wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-100
Aug 26 14:45:45 MiniSamsung NetworkManager[731]: <warn>  [1630003545.0122] platform-linux: do-change-link[3]: failure changing link: failure 5 (Input/output error)
Aug 26 14:45:45 MiniSamsung audit: BPF prog-id=84 op=UNLOAD
Aug 26 14:45:45 MiniSamsung audit: BPF prog-id=83 op=UNLOAD
Aug 26 14:45:45 MiniSamsung wpa_supplicant[777]: wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-100
```

lscpi gave

```
05:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 100
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 100 BGN
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

systemd network devices gave

```
● 3: wlp5s0                     
                     Link File: /usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
                  Network File: n/a
                          Type: wlan
                         State: off (unmanaged)
                          Path: pci-0000:05:00.0
                        Driver: iwlwifi
                        Vendor: Intel Corporation
                         Model: Centrino Wireless-N 100 (BGN)
                    HW Address: 16:c8:03:78:53:87
          HW Permanent Address: 78:92:9c:49:b5:d0 (Intel Corporate)
                           MTU: 1500 (min: 256, max: 2304)
                         QDisc: mq
  IPv6 Address Generation Mode: none
             WiFi access point: (null) (00:00:00:00:00:00)
          Queue Length (Tx/Rx): 4/1
             Activation Policy: up
                    Rx Packets: 0
                    Tx Packets: 0
                      Rx Bytes: 0
                      Tx Bytes: 0
                     Rx Errors: 0
                     Tx Errors: 0
                    Rx Dropped: 0
```